# How to integrate this CodePen code into Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to implement this (https://codepen.io/iprodev/pen/azpWBr) in Vue. How can I do that?

I have tried to make implement this like this

```
<template>
    <div>
        <canvas height="100" id="confetti" width="100"></canvas>
     </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        created () {
            // JS code from codepen
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: this use only canvas, I don't see a need of `vue`

Comment: I have already a web app which is built on Vue. I want to implement this in that app.

Comment: What does the CodePen code do, and what trouble _specifically_ are you having with the integration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Certainly, it is doable. There are a few things you need to do. All the code in the Codepen snippet is wrapped inside `DOMContentLoaded` event handler since you need access to actual DOM tree. With Vue, you cannot use this event as `Vue` applications are SPA and the loaded event will be fired much before your actual view is getting rendered.

In this case, you should use `mounted` event instead of `created` lifecycle event of the component. `mounted` ensures that component's DOM is actually attached to the main document.

Further, you will need access to the actual `HTMLCanvasElement`. Instead of locating it by ID, your Vue.js `$refs` construct like this:

```
<canvas ref="confetti" height="100" width="100"></canvas>
```

Inside your component, you can then access the DOM element as:

```
mounted() {
    this.$refs.confetti // Reference to HTMLCanvasElement
}
```

This is how you avoid using global `id` attributes with Vue.js. Now rest of the code is just how you want to organize it inside your component. You can abstract canvas rendering logic into a separate module and pass Canvas element or the methods can become part of Vue instance.

Third and final. There are a couple of event handlers assigned on `window` object like `resize`. You have to ensure that you are cleaning them up when the component is getting destroyed. If you don't do this, then even if the component is destroyed, these events will continue to trigger handlers. For this use `beforeDestroy` lifecycle event provided by `Vue`. Clean up all your globally registered event handlers.

Comment: Here's a demo that implements @Harshal's suggestions: [codepen](https://codesandbox.io/s/jlk5x73x53)

Comment: Is there a way to stop the animation? Perhaps gracefully?  I'd like to click a button and the confetti would cease to drop and continue off the screen.